# how to expand function with additional strings

Tags: python, string, function, case, expand

I am currently trying to solve some beginners exercises but I am stuck at the point where I am supposed to expand an existing function and also add the string that allows me to ignore upper and lower cases. I do really do not know where in the function I should be adding this last information. I am also supposed to find all the lines where the words appear ('Heaven', 'all', 'you').

Here is what I have now:

```
def all_line_numbers(text, word):
    """
    Returns the line numbers (beginning with 1) where the word appears in
    :param text: Text in which the word is searched for
    :param word: A word to search for
    :return: List of line numbers
    """

    lines = text.splitlines()
    i = 0
    for line in lines:
        i = i + 1
        if word in line:
            return i

    return []
```

and it ends with:

```
#
print()
print("exercise")
words = ['Heaven', 'all', 'you']
for word in words:
    num = all_line_numbers(it_rains, word)
    if num:
        print(f"The word {word} is in the following lines {num}.")
    else:
        print(f"The word {word} was not found!")
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Use the `lower()` function: `if word in line.lower():`

Comment: You can use `.lower()` on `word` and `line` to match them ignoring case.

Comment: thank you, it helped me out! The only problem is, I do get only one result. Meaning it shows me only where the word appears first (in which line). How do I include all the lines of a text? I hope my question is understandable..